# Filter documents of snapshot after received them

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have Streambuilder that get users documents from Firestore and show them as ListView, but I want control who appears and who will be ignored after received documents, I can't use (where) for all cases, you can read my full problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294088/streambuilder-from-firebase-firestore-with-advanced-filtering)

So I want to ask about is there a way to filter documents after received them ?

Comment: No, I want to filter them by some filters like isNotEqualTo, isEqualTo, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo and whereNotIn

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all the docs;
2. Save them somewhere;
3. Query them with a .where( (YourModel element) => element.attribute == true ).toList();
4. Save the queried items in another list and start growing it;

Update --

Example of what I mean:

That's quite easy, you define global variables like:

```
List<YourModel> listOfObjects;
List<YourModel> listOfObjectsQueried;
```

Then inside the builder you can place a condition like:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
   listOfObjects = snapshot.data;
   listOfObjectsQueried = listOfObjects.where((YourModel element) => element.condition == true).toList();
}
if(listOfObjectsQueried != null) {
   return Container(
... here you show your listOfObjectQueried;
);
}
//if it is null
return CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: Can you explain and show example for saving docs after received them from streambuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the [example in FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes):

```
class UserInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  final String cxurrentUid;

  const UserInformation({Key key, this.currentUid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    Query query = users.where('age', isGreaterThan: 20);

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: query.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) => document.data())
              .where((data) => data['uid'] != currentUid)
              .map((data) => ListTile(
                  title: new Text(document.data()['full_name']),
                  subtitle: new Text(document.data()['company']),
                );
              ).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Your working with a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`, not a `Query` anymore.

You will have to convert your `isNotEqualTo`, `isEqualTo`, `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `whereNotIn`:

`isNotEqualTo` ⇒ `where((data) => data[age] != 42`

`isEqualTo` ⇒ `where((data) => data[age] == 42`

`isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` ⇒ `where((data) => data[age] >= 42`

`whereNotIn` ⇒ `where((data) => [42, 67, 239].conatins(data[age])`

I would also recommend having a proper class Model to convert your Firestore Document to Domain Entities.

Comment: I want to use (isNotEqualTo, isEqualTo, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo and whereNotIn)

Comment: See the error that showing to me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66294088/11777291